# Pass variable from node.js + jade (sails) to frontend - Scaping issues

Tags: javascript, json, regex, node.js, pug

I know how to pass the variable, but no matter what i do to parse the string its not getting escaped properly, i'm getting errors like

`VM4244:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position n`

The data is an object that has nested objects with long strings that have quotes and single quotes, some of those are pre-scaped with /

This is the data:

```
var myObj = {
 description {
    en: 'Lorem Ipsum starts in 1981 in Lorem, Ipsum. The so-called "hegemonic"  centers and the \"peripheral others\" nevertheless, in Jacob Karpio\'s own words: "my work is no',
    es: NULL
}
```

This is part of my jade view

```
- var serverSideData = JSON.stringify(myObj)
script.
 var clientSeideData = '!{serverSideData}'
```

I've tried a couple of snippets from similar questions, but none of them seem to work, and even made a regex, but it seems i'm missing something pretty obvious:

```
- var doubleQuoteMatcher = /[^(",|:?\\|{)](")[^(?::|}|,)]/g
- var singleQuoteMatcher = /[^\\](')/g
- var serverSideData = JSON.stringify(myObj).replace(singleQuoteMatcher, "\'").replace(doubleQuoteMatcher, '\"')
```

I've tried more slashes with the same result.

This is one of the regex i made for  the stringified json

https://regex101.com/r/wY3fS6/2

And of course using the scaped version of variable interpolation that comes with jade #{} is way worst.

Any ideas are welcome

Update: It seems my replace is not even affecting the string :S

Update2:

```
- var data = JSON.stringify(institution.toTempSchema(locale)).replace(/\\"/g, '\\\\"').replace(/[^\\](')/g, "\\\'")
```

Works but fails depending on the quoting used

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.stringify` on its own yet? That's supposed to escape quotes automatically.

Comment: @RamenChef of course, i should probably said that, but i'm not overcomplicating stuff because i want too. Just using .stringify yields the same error. It seems there is an issue in my regex on the doubleQuotesMatcher, i'll probably need to emulate the lookbehind to properly match the '\"' string but that's above my regex knowledge. Thanks for suggesting that anyways :)